# Passing a class-member function to a global function as argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I am trying to pass a member function of class A to a global function as parameter. What must I do to make this work? Also, is this a good idea? Context: I want to do this because (the synonym) `doSomething(...)` is a very general function that is used in `main()` as well as in different classes. Thus I can avoid to have several copies of the same code in my Project. What are alternatives (if it's not optimal)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double doSomething(int i, double (*f)(double)) { return (*f)(i); }

class A{
public:
    A(double x) : number(x) {}
    double times(double i) { return ::doSomething(i, &A::multiply);} //calles the global function and gives a member function as parameter
    double multiply(double i) {return number*i;}
private:
    double number;
};

int main() {

    A obj(5.0);
    cout << obj.times(3.5) <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler complains:

```
../src/test5.cpp: In member function ‘double A::times(double)’:
../src/test5.cpp:17:63: error: cannot convert ‘double (A::*)(double)’ to ‘double (*)(double)’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘double doSomething(int, double (*)(double))’
  double times(double i) { return ::doSomething(i, &A::multiply);} //calles the global function and gives a parameter member function as parameter
                                                               ^
../src/test5.cpp:17:65: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  double times(double i) { return ::doSomething(i, &A::multiply);} //calles the global function and gives a parameter member function as parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doSomething` function expects a free function pointer (free function means non-member function). You try to pass a member function pointer to it. This will not work. Why? When you have a free function, say `void f(double)`, you can simply call it:

```
f(3.14);
```

on the other hand, when you have a member (and non-static) function, to call it you need an object, e.g.:

```
obj.m(3.14);
```

and you cannot call a member function without an object. So a member function cannot be used interchangeably with free function, since they are called in different way. Think about the `(*f)(i)` call in the `doSomething` function - what would be the `A` object for `multiply` to call upon?

Your design needs rethinking. If you want to share code, maybe you need some class hierarchy and the common code in the base class?

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 you might do:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<double (double)> do_something_function;
double doSomething(double i, do_something_function f) { return f(i); }

class A{
    public:
    A(double x) : number(x) {}
    double times(double i) {
        do_something_function f = [this] (double i) {
            return this->multiply(i);
        };
        return ::doSomething(i, f);
    }
    double multiply(double i) {
        return number * i;
    }

    private:
    double number;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you call a `non-static` function member of a class via pointer differs from the way you do it on freestanding function because **a pointer to instance is needed**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A;
typedef double (A::*f)(double);
double doSomething(double i, f p, A* ap);

class A {
public:

    A(double x) : number(x) {
    }

    double times(double i) {
        return ::doSomething(i, &A::multiply, this);
    } //calles the global function and gives a member function and pointer to A

    double multiply(double i) {
        return number*i;
    }
private:
    double number;
};

double doSomething(double i, double (A::*fp)(double), A* ap) {
    return (ap->*fp)(i);  // call *fp on *ap
}

int main() {

    A obj(5.0);
    cout << obj.times(3.5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

[example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b84d8e5241c7b7)

Comment: In your example i would still need to declair the type of object `doSomething` wants. This means i would still need a copy of the same code for other object. I think Wojtek Surowka was right about to rethink my design. Thank you for your answer.